# TIBCO splitting string, using string as a splitter

Tags: xml, split, substring, tokenize, tibco

I have below example of input string:

```
test1=123#test2=456#test3=789
```

I wanted to split this string, using "#" (hash sign) as a splitter. To achieve this, I can use example:

```
tib:tokenize("test1=123#test2=456#test3=789","#")
```

and I'll get what I want:

```
test1=123
test2=456
test3=789
```

The problem is, when I wanted to split string, using not char/sign (as previously "#"), but string ("#splitter#"). In example of input string:

```
test1=123#splitter#test2=456#splitter#test3=789
```

I cannot use tokenizer, as it allows only to provide one sign character.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write up a class in Java and use it in your BW project as a **Java Custom Function** activity.

The Java class will return a string array as below

```
return StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("test1=123#splitter#test2=456#splitter#test3=789","#splitter#");
```